# Kendo Grid Custom Filter-Operators

Tags: angular, filter, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I was trying to remove some filter operators from my kendo-grid in angular2 project. As a rule I had to specify the operators that i needed in order to avoid the unwanted operators so I did this to my code:

```
<kendo-grid-column field="ProductName" title="Product Name">
    <ng-template kendoGridFilterMenuTemplate let-filter let-column="column" let-filterService="filterService">
        <kendo-grid-string-filter-menu
        [column]="column"
        [filter]="filter"
        [filterService]="filterService"
        operator="startswith">
            <kendo-filter-startswith-operator></kendo-filter-startswith-operator>
            <kendo-filter-isnotempty-operator></kendo-filter-isnotempty-operator>
        </kendo-grid-string-filter-menu>
    </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```

But the is not empty operator produces error. It gives me this error:[image]
Is there anything that I missed? Help me.